# Can I use a PC power supply in a LCD?

Tags: power-supply, lcd

The LCD's original power supply has the same conectors as a regular PC power supply.
My main concern is if the PC power supply has the correct specs to be used by the LCD.
The original power supply has this specs:

```
200Watt power supply W/PFC

AC Input 115-230V ~ /4-2A / 60-50Hz
DC     +3.3V | +5V | +12V | -5V | -12V | +5Vsb
Output 17 A  | 12A | 10A  | 0.3A| 0.5A | 1.5A
           +3.3V & +5V Total output 65W
```

An this are the specs from the PC power supply

```
450Watt power supply

AC Input 115/230V ~8/4.5A 60/50Hz
DC Output     +3.3V | +5V | +12V | -5V | -12V | +5Vsb
Direct current  28A | 35A | 18A  |0.8A | 0.5A | 2A
Constant Power   230 W    | 216W | 10W | 2.5W | 10W
                     340W        |       23W
-----------------------------------------------------
Power peak           425W        |       33W
```

Can I use this PC power supply to replace the LCD's original power supply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the PC power supply can provide more than the original power supply on all voltages it should be suitable.